# No results match your search criteria in kibana with timestamp

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

I created an index in elasticsearch 6.5.1 successfully loaded the data to that index. there is one field  `"submitted_date"` which is the timestamp. below is the mapping like of this field.

```
"submitted_date": { "type": "date", "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" },
```

then I created the index pattern. I used the `Time Filter field name` as  `"submitted_date"`. after that, I tried to check the data in Discover tab, but data are not showing. there is a message saying that `No results match your search criteria`.

NOTE that I have changed the time in time range picker in every possible way which is on top of the right corner in kibana dashboard.

data appear in Dev Tools tab with elastic queries.

ps : I inserted the data using nodejs with elasticsearch official library, did not used logstash.

I followed [this article](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/20516), but it did not help me.

UPDATE : sample document

```
    {
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 10480,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "tests",
        "_id" : "1214334",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {

          "priority" : "4",
          "submitted_date" : "2018-01-04T18:32:21.000Z",
          "submitted_month" : 0,
          "submitted_month_name" : "January",
          "submitted_day" : 4,
          "submitted_weekday" : "Tuesday",
          "submitted_hour" : 18,
          "submitted_year_month" : "2018-0",
          "submitted_year_month_name" : "2018-January",
          "date_key" : "20180104",
          "year_month_key" : "201801",
          "status" : "Closed"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Inspect request

```
    {
  "version": true,
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "submitted_date",
        "interval": "1d",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Kolkata",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "close_date",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "last_modified_date",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "last_resolved_date",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "submitted_date",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "time_to_resolve",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "submitted_date": {
              "gte": 1514745000000,
              "lte": 1543937620414,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
  }
}
```

Index pattern

```
    function _putMapping() {
    return client.indices.create({
        index: process.env.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX,
           body: {
               settings:{
                index:{
                    "number_of_shards": 1,
                    "number_of_replicas": 5
                },
                    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed" : true
               },
               mappings:{
                   tests:{
                       properties:{
                           "last_modified_date": { "type": "date" },
                           "last_resolved_date": { "type": "date" },
                           "time_to_resolve": { "type": "date" },
                           "submitted_date": { "type": "date", "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" },

                           "date_key": { "type": "integer" },
                           "priority": { "type": "long" },
                           "submitted_hour": { "type": "long" },
                           "submitted_month": { "type": "long" },
                           "submitted_year": { "type": "long" },
                           "submitted_year": { "type": "keyword" },
                           "submitted_year_month": { "type": "keyword" },
                           "submitted_year_month_name": { "type": "keyword" },
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document that should show up?

Comment: I have added the sample document to question

Comment: So if you pick "1 year" you don't see anything? Can you click on "Inspect" at the top and copy the request that Kibana is sending?

Comment: no, I don't get even I pick last 5 years of data, I tried year-to-date as well. I copied the inspect request in question

Comment: I'm also interested to see your index pattern definition, it seems you named it in reverse: `test/tests` instead of `tests/test`

Comment: I update the index pattern as well. I didn't get this `test/tests"

Comment: I meant the index pattern you have in Kibana. Also what is the value of `process.env.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184703/discussion-between-roledenez-and-val).

Comment: value of process.env.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = test

Comment: I think your Kibana index pattern is not setup properly. What pattern did you input?

Comment: I only have one index which is the test, so I used it

Comment: Looking at the sample document data, I think your `submitted_data` field format should be set as `"format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`. Try and see if this fixes the issue..

Answer (score 1):

Your mYour `submitted_date` is coming like `2018-01-04T18:32:21.000Z` but your mapping is set as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

You need to change it to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`.

Comment: then I get this "Invalid format: [yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ]: Illegal pattern component: T"

Comment: i think T and Z must be encapsulated withing single quotes, i have updated the answer, can you try this.

Comment: now it gives me this "Unhandled rejection [mapper_parsing_exception] Failed to parse mapping [reports]: Could not convert [date.index] to boolean :: "

Comment: @Roledenez what if you remove `format`  altogether, and just use `type`?

Comment: if use just type, then data are inserting to index, then it's not recognized as the timestamp in Kibana, no data showing in kibana discover tab